# XML Schema element confusion

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence, complextype

If I have XML

```
...
<BOOK Author="blabla" Edition="3rd">
NOTE
...
PRICE
...
</BOOK>
...
```

XML Schema will be:

```
...
<xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="book">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="note">
               ...
               ...
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
   </xs:sequesce>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

Where this information about author and edition should be?? Please help.

Comment: Identifiers in XML (including element and attribute names) are case sensitive, `book` is not the same as `BOOK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is what you need :

```
    ...

  <xs:element name ="book" type = "booktype"/>

  <xs:complexType name = "booktype">

    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
      . . .
    </xs:sequence>

      <xs:attribute name = "author" type = "xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name = "edition" type = "xs:string"/>

  </xs:complexType>
    ...
```

Comment: If this is correct way to do it... yes i think this is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You declare attributes using

```
<xs:attribute name="Author" type="xs:string"/>
```

or similar, these declarations go *inside* the relevant element's `complexType`, and must be *after* the `sequence`, i.e. between `</xs:sequence>` and `</xs:complexType>`.

```
<xs:element name="BOOK">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NOTE">...</xs:element>
      <xs:element name="PRICE">...</xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Author" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Edition" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Remember that XML element and attribute names are case-sensitive, so if the element is called `BOOK` then the schema must also say `BOOK`, not `book`.